# Xamarin Forms SOAP WebService, how to get data?

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin, soap

I have searched for a few days now and cannot figure this out. I would like to get my results from a WebService. I am using PCL and as far as I can tell we cannot use string as a variable when returning, only void.

```
        WebServiceSoapClient client = new WebServiceSoapClient();
        string result = client.SetDriverAvailAsync(varUserid, varPassword, varLocation, varDateTime);
```

Above is what I'm using to call the method. And the web service was written as such.

```
[WebMethod]
public string SetDriverAvail(string drivername, string password, string location, string datetime)
{
    if (location == "" || datetime == "")
    {
        return "failed";
    }
```

It does a bunch of other stuff. Then returns "success" or "failed". Bottom line is. When i make my Service Reference for a Portable Form in Xamarin the only methods it makes in the Connection Service are public voids.

If I make a Service Reference in all other projects like ASP Web Page, ect. It builds these methods differently. And does let you return a string.

CONFUSED ... THANKS

Comment: Usually a soap service client will expose a completion handler that you set in order to be notified when the method completes.  Something like "OnSetDriverAvailComplete"

Comment: Thats interesting. I will try and research this. Thank you. Cause i do see that method available.

Comment: Hmm .. The SQL query I wrote on the Web Service always completes regardless of the parameters, no exception thrown. So it returns success even when nothing happens. I programmed it so it returns a string "success" or "fail", but I cannot access that string. So currently OnSetDriverAvailComplete is always telling me yes when often its a no.

Comment: If you are also writing the service, I'd suggest making it a REST service instead of SOAP.  These are much easier to work with

Comment: since I made it in .NET it wrote the REST for me as well. But I cannot use REST within Xamarin Forms. Or at least I do not know how. It seems the library is blocked. I'm trying to add client and it needs library System.Net.Http. Or maybe there is another way to add it. I read something about cause its bundled with Silverlight, n that its not possible. I dunno. I'm working outside of Forms right now with Droid only. So, all is not lost. But I would love to have used Forms, make it multiple platform. Thanks for your input.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/

Comment: Thank you. Sorry about that. I'll have to figure out why the httpclient class is not working then. This should work. Plus ill have to learn how to use items and JSON. Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<TodoItem>> (content); Again thank you so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a simplistic answer, but I suggest you read [Xamarin introduction to web services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could figure this all out if doing an Android App only. But I'm unsure how to do this within PCL, the Portable Class Library.